# Communication between Arduino and iOS device

Tags: bluetooth

How can I get weight that has been measured by an Arduino device to show up on an iOS mobile or tablet device as a number?

Thanks.

Warmly,
N.

Answer (score 2):

There are cables that let you plug in to the 30 pin connector and get a connection.

You could also use a BLE shield and write code for both platforms that communicate via BLE, or a WiFi shield.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple apps for this application but first you need the Arduino connected to the internet. It's called Iarduino and the instructables can be found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Arduino-Board-Wirelessly-With-iPhone-iPad/). I don't believe that you can communicate with your ios device with blue tooth. The app should allow for serial communication but I am not an expert on serial.

Comment: You can connect Bluetooth to IOS.

Comment: iOS doesn't support Serial over BlueTooth. So those cheap bluetooth modules don't work. There are other types of Bluetooth profiles do work, but are a bit harder to implement.

Comment: The last several generations of iDevices have supported Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) with arbitrary peripherals, and encapsulating a (low rate) serial stream is possible.  They also support legacy bluetooth, but are locked down to only talk to "approved" peripherals - a restriction which does not apply to BLE.